# Crystal reports - PUSH blob data, image doesn't display

Tags: crystal-reports, blob

I've a crystal report that I'm trying to get a dynamic image displayed.  This is the CRBasic 2008 version that comes with VS 2008, so i can't use the method where we link out to the file, it has to come from the data source.

I'm pushing a strongly typed dataset to the report, which contains a byte[] field.  This dataset is being populated correctly and the BLOB data in the DB is actually an image (verified it by getting it to display in a picture box in a windows form).

I've a BLOBField dragged onto my crystal design surface, but when I view the report, nothing gets displayed.  Anybody have any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Seems to have been a mismatch between the built dataset and what crystal was expecting.  Surprised there was no error, but there you go...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to have been a mismatch between the built dataset and what crystal was expecting. Surprised there was no error, but there you go..